# How to pass PHP variables to Shell?

Tags: php, shell

I have two files:

**wget.php**

```
<?php
include 'theme.php';
/*ceklogin();*/
css();
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
        $dir=$_POST['dir'];
        $link=$_POST['link'];
        exec('touch /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
        exec('echo "'.$link.'" >> /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
        exec('/www/wget_download.sh,$out);
        echo $out[2];
        exit();
    }
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "Download directory:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/><br>";
echo '<br>Download link (one URL per line):<br>';
echo ("<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"13\" cols=\"60\"></textarea><br><br>");
echo '<input type="submit" name="wget-send" value="Send" />';
echo "</form></div>";

foot();
echo '
</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

**wget_download.sh**

```
while [ true ] ; do
    urlfile=$( ls /tmp/wget-download-link.txt | head -n 1 )
    if [ "$urlfile" = "" ] ; then
        sleep 30
        continue
    fi

    url=$( head -n 1 $urlfile )
    if [ "$url" = "" ] ; then
        mv $urlfile $urlfile.invalid
        continue
    fi

    mv $urlfile $urlfile.busy
    wget $url -o /tmp/wget.log -P $dir
    mv $urlfile.busy $urlfile.done
done
```

How do I pass the variable from $dir in PHP to $dir in shell? so for example the $dir in my PHP is:
`/mnt/usb`

I want `/mnt/usb` to be executed in the `wget_download.sh` so it's gonna be like this:

```
wget $url -o /tmp/wget.log -P /mnt/usb
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You could write it in a file and read it by shell. I'm not sure what you are trying to acheive using forms in a shell.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this is very *very* dangerous. Make sure you fully trust anyone able to access your site at all with running arbitrary commands on your server.  I'd suggest ensuring SSL and proper password authentication.

With that caveat out of the way, you can us `putenv("DIR=".$dir);` See "http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php" for a list of restrictions and configurations that might be required.  You may need to prefix the variable names with "PHP_" in both php and in the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I second Daniels warning. That said I would just pass it as an argument:

```
dir="$1"

while [ true ] ; do
    urlfile=$( ls /tmp/wget-download-link.txt | head -n 1 )
    if [ "$urlfile" = "" ] ; then
        sleep 30
        continue
    fi

    url=$( head -n 1 $urlfile )
    if [ "$url" = "" ] ; then
        mv $urlfile $urlfile.invalid
        continue
    fi

    mv $urlfile $urlfile.busy
    wget $url -o /tmp/wget.log -P $dir
    mv $urlfile.busy $urlfile.done
done
```

Which would change you exec call:

```
// the command would actually look like:
// /www/wget_download.sh /path/to/dir
exec('/www/wget_download.sh ' . escapeshellarg($dir),$out);
```